# Property type for the result of a group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got a working group by, but I'm not able to figure out the property type my view model will need to hold the result.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
}
```

Result

```
results[0] FirstName = "Bob" Cars =  {"Mercedes", "bmw"}
results[1] FirstName = "David" Cars =  {"Porsche", "Vauxhall"}


public class DataViewModel
{
    // Need a prop to hold the value of result
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = from p in persons
    group p.car by p.FirstName into g
    select new { FirstName = g.Key, Cars = g.ToList() };

    var model = new DataViewModel();
    model.?? = result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this out by using a complex object to hold the values

```
public class ComplexObject
{
      public string FirstName {get; set; }
      public List<string> Cars {get; set; }
}

var result = from p in persons
    group p.car by p.FirstName into g
    select new ComplexObject { FirstName = g.Key, Cars = g.ToList() };
```

Comment: If you trace `result` then you will find out that the Cars property is a List<List<string>> which cannot be bound to your `ComplexObject`. I wonder whats the point behind this query??